# Ignoring dependencies when installing with yum (Scientific Linux)

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, scientific-linux

How can I ignore dependencies of a single package I am attempting to install using `yum` in Scientific Linux? The answer would presumably the same for CentOS/RHEL.

To elaborate, I am looking to get the utility `lsb_release`, which I know would be put into `/usr/bin/lsb_release`. The command `yum whatprovides /usr/bin/lsb_release` tells me that it is part of the `redhat-lsb` packages (for the respective architectures), but those have a bunch of dependencies, including some X11-related.

Since I am only after the `lsb_release` program, I would like to dodge the "crud" that comes with the dependencies. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you want to install it and "no" dependencies, see https://serverfault.com/a/681848/27813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Installing the X stuff is probably meaningless, unless you have a tiny amount of storage and every MB counts, or if it includes an entire DE, (which it probably doesn't) since that may include some system configuration you don't want.

If you still don't want to go that route, you should be able to find an appropriate .rpm (you might be able to use yum to get the one from the repo without an install, [see here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/yum-downloadonly-plugin/); I haven't tried that and don't know if dependencies will be a hassle; the easiest thing might be to just use [rpmfind](http://rpmfind.net/)).   You can then unpack the rpm using `rpm2cpio` and install the lsb_release binary yourself; check it first with `ldd lsb_release` to make sure the libraries it needs are available.  There may also be other little pieces in the rpm you need.

There are already explanations of rpm2cpio online, so I won't repeat all that.  If you use the `mc` filebrowser you can use that instead of rpm2cpio -- it will let you browse the inside of an rpm the same way you might a tarball or zip file.

Comment: Thanks, that got me started into the correct direction. I'll write my own answer to my question, but still accept your anyway, although it didn't go *all the way* to solve my problem. +1 for now.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the tips from goldilocks' answer, I have come up with this little script which does *exactly* what I want and no more. It was written on and tested on Scientific Linux 6.3, but might work on other RHEL derivatives. I named the script `redhat-lsb.sh` (how uncreative).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
WKPKG=redhat-lsb
WKDIR=$HOME/$WKPKG
[[ -d "$WKDIR" ]] && [[ "x$1" != "x-f" ]] && { echo "ERROR: not removing $WKDIR. Use -f to force it."; exit 1; }
(
    [[ -d "$WKDIR" ]] &&  rm -rf "$WKDIR"
    mkdir "$WKDIR" && \
        cd "$WKDIR" && \
        yumdownloader $WKPKG && \
        cd / && \
        rpm2cpio "$WKDIR"/redhat-lsb-*.$(uname -m).rpm | cpio -idmv
) && rm -rf "$WKDIR"
```

Call as `sudo ./redhat-lsb.sh` or `sudo ./redhat-lsb.sh -f` (the latter removes the working directory if it already exists).

What this does is:

1. uses a folder `$HOME/redhat-lsb` to work in.
2. uses `yumdownloader` to download the package.
3. uses shell globbing to pick the correct `.rpm`: `redhat-lsb-*.$(uname -m).rpm`
4. changes to `/` because this is where we want to install it
5. uses `rpm2cpio` to unpack it to stdout
6. `cpio` catches it and unpacks it into the current directory (this is the step that requires `sudo`)
7. finally removes the working folder

And after that, great success ... it works ... without all the dependencies:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Scientific
Description:    Scientific Linux release 6.3 (Carbon)
Release:        6.3
Codename:       Carbon
```

Turns out the package itself only contains a single statically linked executable. The rest are shell scripts and data.